# Can we broadcast in tmux

Tags: bash, shell, tmux

Now we know that we can do a broadcast all or to a specific group in terminator and execute commands simultaneously on every window.

Can we do the same inside a tmux session?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can, but it has a bit verbose syntax and you should use only short commands. But if you quote it the right way you might be able to post anything. Here just a hello command:

```
for i in `seq 2 3`; do tmux send-keys -t 1:2.$i -l 'hello
'; done
```

This sends to Session 1, Window 2, Pane 2 and 3.

You can find out about the sessions, windows and panes with

```
tmux list-sessions
tmux list-windows
tmux list-panes
```

. Read about the commands in the manual. There are some options to tune output and the way the keys are interpreted.

```
tmux list-panes -aF '#{session_name}:#{window_index}.#{pane_index}'
```

gets a full list of addresses, that you can send to.